# Menu and Main app forms, correct way?

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I have a main Form app. OnLoad it displays with Docstyle=Fill the main menu which is done by user control. If the user selects a choice in that Menu control, it fires an event (with one parameter Choice) which main forms reacts on.
If the choice is run the app, it closes the user control (dipose) and call method starting the app. If the choice is to quit, it calls Application.Exit. Is that alright form programmers point of view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have to save any data and you just like to quit the application, it's the best way to do like you described. If you're using other windows you could use the collection Application.OpenForms and close all open windows.